# What's the issue of my cython(pyx) code converting line to dict?

Tags: string, segmentation-fault, cython

Consider the performance, I write a function in cython to conert line into dict.
The line seems like

`" a: 1    b:2  sdf:3.0   \t ggg:vv"`

The result dict should be

```
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'sdf': '3.0', 'ggg': 'vv'}
```

The cython code is:

```
from libc.string cimport strsep, strlen, strdup
def line2dict(line):
    cdef char* line_str = strdup(line)
    cdef char* item_delim = " \t"
    cdef char* kv_delim   = ":"

    cdef char* kv_str
    cdef char* k_str

    ret = {}
    while 1:
        kv_str = strsep(&line_str, item_delim)
        if kv_str == NULL:
            break
        if strlen(kv_str) == 0:
            continue
        k_str = strsep(&kv_str, kv_delim)
        ret[k_str] = kv_str

    return ret
```

---

Above code can be compiled into .so, imported and called in regular python code, but it may cause "Segmentation fault" in later codes.

I'm a newbie in cython. Can any one please tell me what's wrong with this code?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should not build a python dictionary with C pointers as keys and values.  You probably need to convert those char* into python objects.  See this link: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your segmentation fault is likely a `NULL` return value from your second instance of strsep.  This will happen if you have a line with trailing whitespace, and no ':' delimiter.  Since you are then passing `NULL` as a key into your dictionary, this will cause a segmentation fault.

You should check for a `NULL` value of `k_str` before storing in your dictionary.

There is a second problem.  You are never freeing the memory used to duplicate your string with `strdup`, which will waste excess memory.  I would call `free` which can be cimported from `libc.stdlib` after you have finished tokenizing your string, but before returning.